Error RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed)
I am trying to work out my customised model using PyTorch and calculate the gradients using loss. backward(). I get this error when I run loss.backward() without setting 'retain_graph=True' as I setting this parameter would slow down the fitting procedure. I think my model doesn‘t need to retain a graph since each iteration a new graph can be created. Here is the code for my model:
class GACCR(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,beta,X):
        '''
        :param beta: the coefficient vector of the splines and the bias (beta_0) is at the last element
        :param X: design matrix with basic function (n_dim,n_f+1) n_f is the number of basic function, the last column is all ones for bias
        '''
        super(GACCR,self).__init__()
        assert(beta.shape[0]==X.shape[1])   # the coefficient number match the spline number
        self.beta = torch.nn.parameter.Parameter(beta.clone().detach(),requires_grad=True)
        self.X = X
        self.n_dim = X.shape[0]
        self.n_spline = X.shape[1]-1
        self.cov_pre = torch.zeros((self.n_dim,self.n_dim))


    def forward(self, inputs):
        '''
        :param inputs:   [x_t,r] (n_dim,2)
        :return:
        '''
        theta = (self.X @ self.beta) * inputs[:,0].reshape(self.n_dim,1)

        output= torch.exp(-theta * inputs[:,1].reshape(self.n_dim,1))
        # print('shape of theta:',theta.shape)
        # print(output.shape)

        for i in range(self.n_dim):
            for j in range(i+1):
                self.cov_pre[i][j]= output[abs(i-j)]
        output=self.cov_pre
        return output

and my code for optimization:
num_epoches=10
lr=0.01
optimizer=torch.optim.Adam(GAC_model_cubic.parameters(),lr=lr)
criterion=torch.nn.MSELoss()

training_losses=[0 for _ in range(num_epoches)]

GAC_model_cubic.train()
for epoch in range(num_epoches):
    
    cov_pred=GAC_model_cubic(input.T)
        
    
    loss= criterion(cov_pred,cov_sample)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
        
  
    print(f"loss for epoch {epoch+1}:", loss.item())
    training_losses[epoch] = loss.item()

Any solutions or ideas would be appreciated.
I would like to carry out my optimization procedure without setting 'retain_graph=True' to accelerate the training. Any solutions would be appreciated.
